# How to use array as route parameter properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I have a form with this action:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('products.create.post.attribute',['product'=>$product->id,'total'=>$total_counts,'array'=>$attribute_ids]) }}">
```

So basically, `$attribute_ids` is an array like this:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => 14
  1 => 15
  2 => 16
  3 => 3
  4 => 7
  5 => 8
]
```

And here is the route:

```
Route::post('/create/product/addAttribute/{product}/{total}/{array}', [ProductController::class, 'postAttribute'])->name('products.create.post.attribute');
```

Then at the Controller, I set up the method like this:

```
public function postAttribute(Request $request, Product $product, $total,$array){
```

But I get this error:

**Too few arguments to function ProductController::postAttribute(), 3 passed in C:\projectname\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 4 expected**

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly use array as route parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you using array as parameter name. Change the parameter name and it should work.

**blade**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('products.create.post.attribute',['product'=>$product->id,'total'=>$total_counts,'myarray'=>$attribute_ids]) }}">
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/create/product/addAttribute/{product}/{total}/{myarray}', [ProductController::class, 'postAttribute'])->name('products.create.post.attribute');
```

**controller**

```
public function postAttribute(Request $request, Product $product, $total, $myarray){
```

Comment: Now I get `Array to string conversion` on View

Comment: can you pass the whole error message, please?

Comment: `Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\root\resources\views\admin\samples\sampleProduct\addAttribute.blade.php)`

Comment: @nagidi this error comes from your blade. you try to print a array. it should that you pass some parameter to your view. then you have to iterate the array in your view.

Comment: @nagidi you understand? :-)

Comment: No I didn't :((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242618/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-nagidi).

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass array in the url. You have pass your array data in string format.
There is two way to pass data :

1. **In URL** - which you are doing .
2. **Form data** - using inpur field.

You must have to make a string of that array using `implode`

Either create foreach and inside it create `input` with `name="attribute[]"` add id in input field. This way you will get `$request->attribute` in array.

Comment: Good point, too!